# Coordinating props of encapsulated components when rendering data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, components

I am building a recipe box in reactJS. My objective is hide ingredients within the button, listing the recipe title. Thus when a person clicks on a button titled "cheesecake" they will see its respective ingredients. The booleans in communicating when and when not to do this makes sense as it relates to "Onclick". However, I'm unsure of how to coordinate this action when fetching data given that my ingredients data (this.props.ingredients) is implicated within recipetitlebutton component. I tried re-initializing the ingredients component within the title button thinking that I can just define it within the recipeTitleButton when I mapped over the data. However, this didn't work and it didn't feel clean. Anyway, I hope this makes sense. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

```
var recipes = [{
  recipe_title: "Cheesecake",
  ingredients: "cream cheese, graham crackers, butter, eggs"
}, {
  recipe_title: "Lasagna",
  ingredients: " ricotta cheese, ground beef, pasta shells, parsely"
}, {
  recipe_title: "Spaghetti",
  ingredients: "noodles, pasta sauce, ground beef"
}]

var RecipeTitleButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showIngredients: false
    }
  },
  onClick: function() {
    this.setState({
      showIngredients: true
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    <Ingredients ingredients={this.props.ingredients}/>
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" className="recipe_title_button" class="btn btn=primary btn-lg">{this.props.recipe_title}</button>
        {this.state.showIngredients ? <Ingredients/>: null}
    </div>
    )
  }
})

var Ingredients = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="ingredients" className="recipe_title_ingredients">
        {this.props.ingredients}
  </div>
    )
  }
})

var MainRecipeDisplay = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      recipeDataObject: recipes
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var Pages = this.state.recipeDataObject.map(function(recipeContents) {
<RecipeTitleButton recipe_title={recipeContents.recipe_title} ingredients={recipeContents.ingredients}/> 
    })
    return (
      <div>
      {Pages}
  </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<MainRecipeDisplay/>, document.getElementById('content'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're not actually passing the click handler to any of the elements. So you've defined the `onClick` method in `RecipeTitleButton`, but you're not passing this to anything. The solution is probably as simple as passing the `<button>` element a property `onClick={/* The function that you want to fire on click */}`.

First of all, change the name of the click handler to something like `onClickHandler`, for sanity. Click handlers are called with an event argument, which you probably don't need for your purposes but is important to know about (for example, if you need to prevent event propagation or have the click handler figure out which button was clicked).

Then the `render` function for `RecipeTitleButton` should look like:

```
render: function() {
  <Ingredients ingredients={this.props.ingredients}/>
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" className="recipe_title_button" onClick={this.onClickHandler.bind(this)} class="btn btn=primary btn-lg">{this.props.recipe_title}</button>
      {this.state.showIngredients ? <Ingredients/>: null}
  </div>
  )
}
```

In case you're wondering, we bind the function to `this` so that the context remains the `RecipeTitleButton` component, instead of the window.

Oh, as an aside, it'd be easier to test this if you put it in a JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out. Was very simple. First, React doesn't recognize changing the setState value with a mere {setState({showingredients: true}). I had to use a function to make this explicit {setState(function(){return showIngredients:true)}. Second,in order to render the ingredients component within in my recipeTitle component, I only had to indicate props within {this.showIngredients ? :"null"/>. This way, I was allowed to define the ingredients prop within my recipeTitleButton. Code is Below:

```
var recipes = [{
  title: "Cheesecake",
  ingredients: "cream cheese, graham crackers, butter, eggs"
}, {
  title: "Lasagna",
  ingredients: " ricotta cheese, ground beef, pasta shells, parsely"
}, {
  title: "Spaghetti",
  ingredients: "noodles, pasta sauce, ground beef"
}]

var Layout = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      recipeDataObject: recipes,
      showIngredients: false
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    var recipeContents = this.state.recipeDataObject.map(function(currentRecipe) {
      return (
        <RecipeTitleButton title={currentRecipe.title} ingredients={currentRecipe.ingredients}/>
      )
    })
    return (
      <div>
       {recipeContents}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var RecipeTitleButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showIngredients: false
    }
  },
  handleRecipeButtonClick: function() {
    **this.setState(function() {
      return {
        showIngredients: true
      }**
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleRecipeButtonClick.bind(this)} className="recipe_button">{this.props.title}</button>
        **{this.state.showIngredients && <Ingredients ingredients={this.props.ingredients}/>}**
    </div>
    )
  }
})

var Ingredients = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
    <div className= "ingredients_list">
        {this.props.ingredients}
    </div>
    )
  }
})
```